# TextBox Do not Auto Scroll Down With ScrollViewer

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm using `TextBox` inside a `ScrollViewer`. In edit mode, `TextBox` auto-scroll works if we disable the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` property of ScrollViewer. If we set it to Visible or Auto, `TextBox` do not ScrollDown automatically. Also TextBox's `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` Property do not work in Windows Phone it's works on Windows 8.

I'm not getting how to do this. Scrolling and long text both are compulsory.

Also I got this [Post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx) to make scrollable `TextBlock`, but as I'm new to windows phone. I don't know how to do the same with `TextBox`.

Comment: Same problem i faced earlier, but couldn't find perfect solution yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to change the inside of the `TextBox` control to be a `ScrollViewer`, by editing its default template.

Default style with `ContentControl` changed to `ScrollViewer` (7th line from bottom):

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectionBackground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectionForeground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxSelectionForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ReadonlyBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ReadonlyBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ReadonlyBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxReadOnlyBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBorderBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="MainBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}"/>
                    <Border x:Name="ReadonlyBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="Transparent" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="Transparent" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxInnerMargin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How to use:

```
<TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1}"/>
```

I had a hard time finding this information originally. I hope it helps you and other WP devs.

Comment: Thanks mleroy, this works perfect. thanks a lot. but how to overcome the uielement 2048 pixels limit problem for the long text

Comment: Glad it helped. I'm aware of the 2048px issue in general but haven't explored that problem, sorry.

Comment: using the above code i'm not seeing the 2048px limit problem, means i can see the large text as well. but the problem is large text is loading slowly. on scrolling it takes time to load the next content.. can you plz check this thing may be this can overcome the height limit problem. else its working good for small text.